# PGN chess parser, how to deal with variations

Tags: c#, chess

I am doing a chess trainer in C#. The positions are from PGN files.

A chess game can be annotated in a PGN file (not a PNG, which is an image file). For example: 2. Qxe4 (2. Qxf3 gxf3 3. Kh1 a6 (3... a5)) 2... dxe4 This means that WHITE takes a piece in e4 with his QUEEN (Qxe4), but he can play Qxf3, this is a variation. The question is how to store and retrieve the moves in order, first the variations (enclosed by parenthesis) and last the main line. Variations can be nested one in other. In this example the first variation would be: 2. Qxf3 gxf3 3. Kh1 a5, the second 2. Qxf3 gxf3 3. Kh1 a6, last: 2. Qxe4 dxe4,
I am loading the FEN position correctly, i have the moves in a string[] variable, but i can not deal with the variations. The variations are enclosed by the parenthesis.

Can you help me? how can i store the main line and the variations and later retrieve them for asking the player the correct move? The program first ask for more nested variations and the main line is the last.

I think something like a recursive function, buy i do not know how to deal with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put some code to get directions.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Can you give a complete example, understandable by non-master-chess-player programmers?

Comment: Thanks for your interest. A chess game can be annotated in a PGN file (not a PNG, which is an image file). For example: 2. Qxe4 (2. Qxf3 gxf3 3. Kh1 a6 (3... a5)) 2... dxe4       This means that WHITE takes a piece in e4 with his QUEEN (Qxe4), but he can play Qxf3, this is a variation. The question is how to store and retrieve the moves in order, first the variations (enclosed by parenthesis) and last the main line. Variations can be nested one in other. In this example the first variation would be: 2. Qxf3 gxf3 3. Kh1 a5, the second 2. Qxf3 gxf3 3. Kh1 a6, last:           2. Qxe4 dxe4, thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation

Comment: A recursive parser would be a natural implementation, but it can lead to stack overflows for deeply nested variations.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own [top-down parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top-down_parsing), or you could use a parser generator tool such as [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/about.html) to generate a parser for you.  There is already a [formal PGN grammar definition for use with ANTLR](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/pgn/PGN.g4), so that's probably the quickest method.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear whether you need help in parsing or in representing the  moves, but as you say a String[] isn't working I assume it's modelling the moves that is the problem. Personally, I'd simply use a class to represent each move which could store a number of potential next moves, e.g.:

```
private static class ChessMove {
    private String algebraicMove;
    private List<ChessMove> nextMoves = new ArrayList<>();
    // Maybe add a variation number too?

    public ChessMove(String algebraicMove) {
        this.algebraicMove = algebraicMove;
    }

    public void addMove(ChessMove chessMove) {
        nextMoves.add(chessMove);
    }

    public List<ChessMove> getNextMoves() {
        return nextMoves;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ChessMove firstMove = new ChessMove("e4");

    firstMove.addMove(new ChessMove("e6")); // Add French defence
    firstMove.addMove(new ChessMove("c5")); // Add Sicilian defence
}
```

... the ChessMove class could happily represent a full PGN game with any number of variations.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it. First i am going to study the uses of ArrayList for understanding your code and i will try to implement your code. Thanks again!

Comment: In this class i can to represent each move with its comments, token and more, isn't it? When i parse the file, it has to be in recursive manner i think, because the variations are nested with parenthesis as marker.

Comment: Ah - not sure if you'll have ArrayList in C# - a ChessMove[] array would work equally well - though I'm sure there will be some equivalent list class which is easier to use. You could also add fields for things like comments if you wanted, yes.